# A norm in $C^1([0,1]) $

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have to prove that the following function is a norm in $C^1([0,1])$:
$$\|f\|=\left(f^2(0)+\int_0^1 (f'(t))^2dt\right)^{1/2}.$$

I am in trouble proving the triangle inequality, we have

$$\|f+g\|^2=[f(0)+g(0)]^2+\int_0^1 [f'(t)+g'(t)]^2dt$$
where
$$\int_0^1 [f'(t)+g'(t)]^2dt\leq\int_0^1[f'(t)]^2 dt+2\int_0^1|f'(t)||g'(t)|dt+\int_0^1[g'(t)]^2 dt$$ and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\leq\int_0^1[f'(t)]^2 dt+2\left(\int_0^1|f'(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1|g'(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}+\int_0^1[g'(t)]^2 dt+\left(\left(\int_0^1|f'(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\int_0^1|g'(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\right)^2.$$
My problem now is to prove that $$[f(0)+g(0)]^2\leq [f(0)]^2+[g(0)]^2$$
to then join the previous inequality and thus obtain the triangular inequality

Comment: You cannot prove that because it's not true. Generally $(a+b)^2\leq a^2+b^2~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~a^2+2ab+b^2\leq a^2+b^2~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~2ab\leq 0$. So unless you always have $f(0)\cdot g(0) \leq 0$ what you want to prove isn't ture

Comment: You should try to use the Minkowski inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality